# ¿Como conectar phonegap /Apache Cordova a SQL Server?

Tags: sql, cordova

Acabo de iniciar en el mundo de las aplicaciones híbridas,con Apache Cordova el detalle es que sólo es  HTML, CSS y JS; el problema es que no sé cómo conectar JavaScript directo con SQL.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo, o alguna alternativa?

Comment: Una aplicacion movil de ningun tipo(hibrida o nativa) puede conectarse directamente a una base de datos SQL, deberas usar un servicio web que proveea las datos a tu aplicacion probablemente usando una arquitectura REST exponiendo los datos de tu base de datos en JSON haciendo facil consumirlos desde cordova.

Comment: @Jesus eso mismo podrías publicarlo como respuesta, quizás agregando algún ejemplo o referencia

Answer (score 2):

Yo desarrollé un plugin para poder conectarse en forma directa a SQL Server sin pasar por un servidor intermedio, es de código abierto y se puede instalar como cualquier otro plugin. Aquí puedes ver la [página del proyecto en GitHub](https://github.com/SergioDosSantos/cordova-plugin-sqlserver) (o en [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlserver)).

El plugin conecta derecho a la base de datos, como si fuera una app desktop. Es decir, pones los parámetros de la base de datos, servidor, usuario, password, etc. y después ejecutas querys directamente.

Éste es un ejemplo de cómo funciona. Primero conectándose a la base de datos y luego realizando una consulta:

```
// inicializar conexión a la base de datos
SqlServer.init("192.168.0.120", "SQLEXPRESS", "sa", "pass", "db", function(event) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}, function(error) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});

// ejecución de una consulta
SqlServer.executeQuery("select * from test_table where test_code=1", function(event) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}, function(error) {
  alert("Error : " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Interesante. ¿Cómo lo haces sin servidor intermedio?

Comment: Lo conectas derecho a la base de datos, como si fuera una app desktop. Es decir pones los parámetros de la base de datos, server, usuario, password, etc y después ejecutas querys directamente.

Comment: Genial. Se ve un plugin interesante. Gracias por compartirlo.

Comment: gracias bro! éxitos y sigue con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción seria crear un webservice que te entregue un json para obtener la información necesaria.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a instanciarla dentro de una aplicacion no se puede. La forma mas comun de hacer persistencia en aplicaciones hibridas con cordova es instalar el plugin [sqlite de cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) (y en nativas crear directamente una base de datos sqlite) y conectarte a algun servicio hospedado en tu servidor que si este conectado al motor de base de datos que deseas. Asi, recibes desde tu servidor los datos necesarios, haces la persistencia en tu base de datos sqlite local de tu aplicacion y envias y recibes datos desde/hacia tu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una base de datos en producción en SQLServer, entonces no tienes otra opción que usarla en efecto. Si es una base de datos nueva, te recomiendo pienses bien si realmente necesitas SQLServer.

- ¿Necesitas guardar registros intensivamente?
- ¿Es posible que hayan muchas operaciones de escritura en un mismo instante?

Si la respuesta es afirmativa para las preguntas entonces SQLServer es tu mejor opción. En aplicaciones donde la escritura es muy intensiva y donde pueden haber múltiples transacciones en parelelo, SQLite no es una buena opción debido a que éste motor solo soporta una transacción en el momento.

> SQLite tiene un mecanismo de "locking" la cual bloquea la base de datos en un aplicación de escritura para asegurarse que solo haya una transacción en un determinado instante

SQLite es una alternativa de facto para aplicaciones móviles, es rápida, es ACID compilant y sobre todo, portable. El 90% de las aplicaciones móviles que tienes instaladas, usan éste motor de base de datos.

### Usando una API para comunicarse base de datos remota

No es posible (al menos, hasta donde tengo entendido) usar SQLS en Cordova, no he encontrado plugin para ésto. Sin embargo, aún si hubiese, creo no sería la forma óptima de tener una comunicación exitosa. Una API REST es muy útil en estos escenarios, ya que **se abstrae la lógica de negocio en un solo servicio** que puede ser compartido entre varios clientes.

Por ejemplo, teniendo una API, aislas toda la lógica de tu sistema y desde tu aplicación Cordova, web o incluso desktop, podrías consumirla y efectuar las mismas operaciones, **ignorando completamente cómo están implementadas** y qué motor de base de datos se utiliza.

Por ejemplo, las siguientes acciones puedes consumirlas desde cualquier cliente:

- `GET /users`: obtener todos los usuarios
- `GET /users/:id`: obtener un usuario por id
- `POST /users`: crear un usuario
- `PUT /users/:id`: actualizar un usuario
- `DELETE /users/:id`: eliminar un usuario

Desde tu aplicación Cordova solo tienes que usar AJAX para comunicarte con la API:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'json'
})
.done(users => {
  // hacer algo con los usuarios
});
```

**NOTA:** Si utilizas éste método recuerda establecer el `origin`: `<access origin="*" />`.